# O que é o "^" do python?

Tags: python, operadores

Tava vendo o que é, é ta falando "xor", mas se eu dou 5^11 resulta em 14 e 5^5, 0? O que é esse resultado exatamente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de olharmos isso, é bom antes estudarmos operadores *bit a bit*. [Operadores bit a bit](https://wiki.python.org.br/BitwiseOperators) são formas de operadores assim como **+**, **-**, ***** ou **/** são [operadores aritméticos](https://www.learnpython.org/pt/Operadores_b%C3%A1sicos).

Para começar, sabemos que o computador opera apenas com valores binários (ou 0 ou 1), que ao invés de utilizar a nossa [base decimal](https://www.todamateria.com.br/sistema-de-numeracao-decimal/), que possui 10 números possíveis em cada posição de um algarismo num número, ele utiliza a base 2. Tudo quando é informação que você possa imaginar que esteja passando pelo seu processador agora, está sendo processada em duas possibilidades diferentes.

O Python, como um software que opera sob este computador, trabalha da mesma maneira. É aí que entra esses operadores.

### [Sistema binário](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_numera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_bin%C3%A1rio)

Dizemos base, por que realmente podemos representar este número em forma de potência. Por exemplo, o número 142 é o mesmo que

> (1 x 10^2) + (4 x 10^1) + (2 x 10^0)
>
> [um vezes dez ao quadrado mais quatro vezes dez elevada a primeira mais duas vezes dez elevado a zero]

Sendo assim, estamos representando o 10 como uma base numa potência. Na base binária, funciona da mesma forma:

> **Qual o valor decimal de 101?**
>
> 1 x 2^2 = 4
> 0 x 2^1 = 0
> 1 x 2**0 = 1 (qualquer número elevado a 0 é 1)
> 4 + 0 + 1 = 5

### E os operadores?

São vários operadores que trabalham com lógica muito diferentes entre si, tais que os principais são o &, ^ e |. Eles passam bit a bit daquele número processando de acordo o seu tipo.

Primeiro, vou tratar do operador da sua pergunta: o operador XOR.

O operador <kbd>XOR</kbd>, ou <kbd>OU EXCLUSIVO</kbd> (<kbd>^</kbd>): a saída de cada bit é 1 se, e somente se, um único bit da entrada tiver valor 1.

**EXEMPLO:**

```py
x = 7 # 111 em binário  
y = 5 # 101 em binário  
z = x ^ y # 010 em binário, ou 2 em decimal.
```

O operador <kbd>OR</kbd>, ou <kbd>OU</kbd> (<kbd>|</kbd>): a saída de cada bit é 1 se pelo menos um bit de entrada tiver valor 1. Ele se difere quanto ao XOR, por que o XOR exige que seja exclusivo (ou um, ou outro, nunca ambos), enquanto este também é válido se ambos forem 1.

**EXEMPLO:**

```py
x = 7 # 111 em binário  
y = 5 # 101 em binário  
z = x | y # 111 em binário, ou 7 em decimal.
```

O operador <kbd>AND</kbd>, ou <kbd>E</kbd> (<kbd>&</kbd>): a saída de cada bit é 1 se, e somente se, ambos os bits tiverem valor 1.

**EXEMPLO:**

```py
x = 7 # 111 em binário  
y = 5 # 101 em binário  
z = x ^ y # 101 em binário, ou 5 em decimal.
```

Answer (score 5):

KaigoGames,

imagine o seguinte o número 5 (decimal) é representado por 0101 (binário) e o número 11 (decimal) é representado por 1011 (binário) logo se está realizando uma operação [XOR](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porta_XOR) você terá o resultado de 14 (decimal) que é representado por 1110 (binário).

Comment: obrigado, entendi

Answer (score -4):

Bit a bit OU exclusivo do operador: Quando os dois binário bit correspondente diferente e o resultado é 1